# Как создать функцию как новый объект в python?

Tags: python, функции, замыкания

Есть код:

```
funcs = []
for x in range(10):
    def func(arg):
        return x+arg
    
    funcs.append(func)

print(funcs[2](1))
```

output: 10

Он создает список из 10 функций (элементов), каждая функция должна иметь аргумент x в соответствии с индексом x.

Т.е. при вызове `func[2](1)` должно возвращаться 2 + 1 = 3, но возвращается 10. Это происходит потому, что все элементы списка ссылаются на одну функцию, конечную из цикла. Новые функции не создаются.

И в этом случае x = 9, 9+1 = 10.

Мне нужно чтобы у каждой функции был свой уникальный x в соответствии с циклом. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6):

> Это происходит потому, что все элементы списка ссылаются на одну функцию, конечную из цикла. Новые функции не создаются.

Это не так, достаточно добавить вывод `id(func)`, и увидеть что `id` каждый раз выводится разный, значит и объекты функций разные. Или после цикла вывести на печать список, получится что-то такое, видно, что id разные:

```
[<function func at 0x7fae88593d90>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7880>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7be0>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7c70>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7d00>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7d90>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7e20>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7eb0>, <function func at 0x7fae884b7f40>, <function func at 0x7fae882b4040>]
```

Причина описанного поведения не в том, что функция одна и та же, а в том что все созданные функции обращаются они к одной и той же глобальной переменной, поэтому и поведение у них одно и то же.

Каждая созданная функция не запоминает значение глобальной переменной `x` из прошлого, она при вызове обращается к самой этой переменной, с актуальным ее значением на момент вызова, после цикла это значение равно 9.

Можно обернуть функцию в лямбду, передав текущее значение `x` через параметр по умолчанию:

```
def func(arg, x):
    return x+arg


funcs = []
for x in range(10):
    funcs.append(lambda arg, x=x: func(arg, x))

print(funcs[2](1))  # Вывод: 3
```

Более красивый вариант - вместо лямбды использовать [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
funcs.append(functools.partial(func, x=x))
```

Или сделать функцию - фабрику функций, которая будет создавать экземпляр функции с заданным значением `x`, и `x` будет браться из локальной переменной внешней функции (на момент вызова, в котором была создана внутренняя функция):

```
def function_factory(x):
    def func(arg):
        return x+arg
    return func


funcs = []
for x in range(10):
    funcs.append(function_factory(x))

print(funcs[2](1))  # Вывод: 3
```